# Evaluate the following determinants given the following :

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Determinant given is

$$\begin{vmatrix}
a & b & c\\
d & e & f\\
g & h & i
\end{vmatrix} = \frac72$$

This is my work:

\begin{align}
\begin{vmatrix}
2a & 2b & 2c\\
d + 5g & e + 5h & f + 5i\\
-g & -h & -i
\end{vmatrix} 
&\stackrel{R_3(-1)}{\longrightarrow}
\begin{vmatrix}
2a & 2b & 2c\\
d + 5g & e + 5h & f + 5i\\
g & h & i
\end{vmatrix}\\
&\stackrel{R_3(-5)+R_2}{\longrightarrow}
\begin{vmatrix}
2a & 2b & 2c\\
d & e & f\\
g & h & i
\end{vmatrix}\\
&=\frac72 \cdot 2 = 7
\end{align}

I am not sure if this is correct, however. Someone told me the answer is $-7$?

Comment: Multiplying $R_3$ by $-1$ multiplies the result by $-1$

Comment: okay I assumed it would just make row 3 positive. So instead I should just factor out -1 and then I am assuming the answer would be -7 and I was wrong?

Comment: Apart from the missing factor $(-1)$, the proof is correct and the result is $-7$